# Method put(Integer, Integer) in the type Map<Integer,Integer> is not applicable for the arguments (String, Integer)

Tags: java, dictionary

I have written some code which will get the key of each entry in a balances map, and then if it matches the key in the purse name map, replace the value in the balances map with the corresponding name of the purse.

There is *no problem* with the code, and it works as expected, see below:

### Purse name map:

```
purseNames = {497=ASC, 64339=Football, 488=BC, 169=Pre-pay, 170=Cafeteria, 171=Lettings, 172=Dinner}
```

### Example balance data:

```
balances = {497=-7000, 64339=0, 169=-500, 170=0, 172=0}
```

### My Code:

```
// For every account in the List of Accounts
for (AccountGridRow accountGridRow : accountGridRows) {

        // The original balances
        Map<Integer, Integer> balances = accountGridRow.getBalances();

        // Go through and match up the ID's with their corresponding names
        for (int i = balances.size() - 1; i >= 0; i--){
            Object balanceKey = balances.keySet().toArray()[i];
            for (int j = 0; j < purseMap.size(); j++) {
                Object purseKey = purseMap.keySet().toArray()[j];
                if (purseKey.equals(balanceKey)){
                    String purseName = purseMap.values().toArray()[j].toString();

                    // Take the old balance value and put it in the new map, 
                    // with the new name key. 
                    Integer obj = balances.remove(balanceKey);
                    balances.put(purseName, obj);
                    break;
                    }
            }
        }
```

### My results:

```
balances = {ASC=-7000, Dinner=0, Football=0, Cafeteria=0, Pre-pay=-500}
```

### The problem:

I need to be able to replace the 'balances' with the new balances in my result set, for each account, however I cannot do this, as the map types are different. The 'AccountGridRow' class expects:

```
Map<Integer, Integer>
```

However, my new, modified map is in the type:

```
Map<String, Integer>
```

I cannot change the type that AccountGridRow expects, because it is being used by many other places in the code.

### Dreamy result:

This will eventually be serialised to JSON, example account entry, below:

```
"accounts" 
[
  {
"accountId": 1123,
"accountNum": "1009",
"lastname": "Bar",
"firstname": "foo",
"address": "91 Awesome St, Awesomeville, Somewheresota, 45251",
"class": "Tigers",
"status": "Active",
"balances": {

    // replace with the balances, with the purse names instead of purse ID. 

},
"yearRegistered": "2005"
  }
]
```

Does anyone have a way I can get around this please? I have tried to use a newBalance map by replacing the line:

```
balances.put(purseName, obj);
```

with

```
Map<String, Integer> newBalances = new HashMap<>();
newBalances.put(purseName, obj);
```

But I cannot figure out how to replace the balances with the 'newBalances' without getting a 'not applicable for the arguments' error.

Comment: I really don't get what you are asking for. If you need an Integer instead of a string, than *you* have to define that mapping from an Integer value to a string.

Comment: Is that a [mcve] ? This is complete, but not focused on a problem, so I am a bit confused here. You have an `Integer` that you want to put into a `String` ? Well `Integer.toString` is the simple solution, based on your need, this would be enough.

Comment: I think the OP wants the reverse. Use a String where it expects an Integer. An option is to not parametrize the Map and use the raw Map type instead.

Comment: @ramp, might be, but I would just try to parse the `String` and catch any parse exception. It is said, I believe, that the Map can't be change because it is used in other places. (and I found Raw type messy ;) )

Comment: @AlexH, you are right - Raw type is messy. But take a look at look at the OP's post - the String cannot be converted to an Int because its a genuine String. Its not a String representation of Int. For example the original Map had '497=ASC' as a key value which he wants to replace with 'ASC=-7000'. Basically he wants to convert an Int (Item code) to a Text (String description)

Comment: @ramp That's exactly what I was trying to do, though I'm a she, not a he! ;)

Comment: @greenTree, use a raw type. I dont think you have any other option.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Answer was provided for this problem, on another question I asked here:

[Can I override a Map<Integer, Integer> with Map<String, Integer>?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/44885280/can-i-override-a-mapinteger-integer-with-mapstring-integer)

Answer (score 0):

If I understand it correctly, you want to convert a String to an Integer? 
This answer seems to simple, but can't you use

```
balances.put(new Integer(purseName), obj);
```

Answer (score 0):

Simply write a method to convert, String values to int and apply that method tp each value you are using for key, 
also watch out for malformed strings which could result in exception. you may define default values for these cases:

```
int convertToInt(String value) { 
try {  
   return Integer.parseInt(value);  
} catch(NumberFormatException nfe) {  
  // Log exception.
  return 0;
  }  
}
```