# Can I override a Map<Integer, Integer> with Map<String, Integer>?

Tags: java, dictionary, collections

I have the following class **AccountWebappGridRow**, which extends **AccountGridRow**:

```
public class AccountWebappGridRow<Accounts> extends AccountGridRow implements java.io.Serializable {
```

**AccountGridRow** contains has this field:

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> balances;
```

With **public** getters/setters:

```
public Map<Integer, Integer> getBalances() {
  return balances;
}

public void setBalances(Map<Integer, Integer> balances) {
   this.balances = balances;
}
```

Is there a way that I can somehow override/replace the inherited

```
private Map<Integer, Integer> balances;
```

in my **AccountWebappGridRow**...with this instead:

```
private Map<String, Integer> balances;
```

Comment: Not without changing the AccountGridRow class. But that looks like a typical job for using generics.

Comment: Short answer: "no".

Comment: Regardless of whether you can (and you probably could, because of type erasure), you should not. Any code that calls `getBalances()` or `setBalances()` on an `AccountGridRow` instance expects it to work with a `Map<Integer, Integer>`. That code won't work if it gets a `Map<String, Integer>` instead, because the `AccountGridRow` happens to also be an `AccountWebappGridRow`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Sure. You can do that ... as soon as **you** can provide a mapping that will allow you to turn an **Integer** key into a String key.

In other words: your class knows about Integer keys and values. Of course you can now add another map that uses the same values. The only thing required is that **you** create a *meaningful* mapping function. *Meaningful* meaning: a function that fits *your* requirements. We don't know what content the `Map<String, Integer>` is supposed to hold; so we can't tell you how to properly map keys here!

The most simple answer could be to use

```
String stringKey = someIntegerKey.toString();
```

resp.

```
Integer integerKey = Integer.parseString(stringKey);
```

With those *mappings* you can now take the *internal* map and create a "result" map that uses Integers again.

In other words: you can add that new map to your class; or you can completely rework your class and change that `balances` field to use a different key. All of that is just "work" - and all of that relies on *you* defining how you get from Integer to String keys; and vice versa.

Comment: I wonder if that `Map<String, Integer>` map really has numbers in these Strings. I would assume the answer is either "no" or "now, but not for long" :D.

Comment: That is why I used *meaningful* . We don't know anything about his integer / string keys ( I am still trying to decrypt the question he asked an hour ago about the same thing). He has to map. But as soon as he defines a mapping, he should be fine.

Comment: Just eww... Why having another map instance if it can be solved with one map? You have two maps for connecting a string to another integer using the value of the first map as the key of the second map ? 

Comment: @KarelG As written before - the OP has written a similar question an hour ago. Maybe you can figure what is trying to achieve. I am just describing how he can solve his problem (the way he intends to).

Comment: Hey, thanks for taking the time to write this out. This solves my problem. I realised the previous question didn't have the clearest explanation!

Comment: @GhostCat well, I checked his other question after I've submitted my question. I didn't have seen the other question. With that context, then your answer is OK. But in general? I don't approve this way.The answer on other question is simply connecting the `Map<Integer, Integer>`  with purseNames by using the same keys.

Comment: @KarelG Yes, the other question gives some background. But I think my answer still makes quite some sense in "isolation". He has a class that has a certain map; and he asks how he can "wrap" around that map. And my answer gives an option to do that.

Answer (score 1):

you can define a method that using stream turn the `Map<Integer, Integer>` into a `Map<String, Integer>`

```
public Map<String, Integer> getBalancesStringString() {
    return balances.entrySet()
            .stream()
            .collect(Collectors.toMap(e -> e.toString(), e -> e.getValue()));
}
```

Comment: `e -> e.toString(), e -> e.getValue()` ... I wonder if your second argument tells you why the first one is wrong (or you should explain why you used that for generating the string).

Comment: And I don't get why you use `e.toString()` instead of using the key.